# LCP for 2 strings of a vector with permutations - performance issue

Tags: c++, string, vector

In this problem, I'm given a vector of strings, and N ranges of the exact same vector. The task is to print out the size of the longest common prefix of 2 strings in the given range, the indexing starts from 1.

**Example input**

```
4
aab abc aac xba
3
2 3
1 3
3 4
```

**Example output**

```
1
2
0
```

So in the first case the LCP is in the range of 2 and 3 (both inclusive) which means the strings are `aab` and `abc`. Their common prefix is just `"a"`, so the output is 1.

**What I've done:**

Permute the vector and use 2 for loops for the LCP. If the LCP is greater than the previous one, get its value.
The problem with this is that it's very time inefficient, so I'm asking if there's an already known way of like storing some lengths so the program doesn't have to repeat iterating through some strings?

Any help would be appreciated.